# Flutter - textColor from TextButtonTheme not applied in application

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ThemeData to style text inside my buttons. Setting font family and even text size works perfectly, but the text colour is not applied for some reason. It works if I manually apply the given TextStyle in my code, but that's not how it should work, no?

Of course, I am setting my ThemeData in my Application class. I emphasize that some data from TextButtonThemeData and ElevatedButtonThemeData work, but the text colour not...

Like that it applies textSize and other's but NOT textColour:

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('TAP HERE'),
)
```

And only like that the colour is correctly applied:

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('TAP HERE', style: TextStyles.textButton),
)
```

My ThemeData:

```
final applicationTheme = ThemeData(
  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  primarySwatch: MyColors.primary,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: MyColors.primary.shade900,
    toolbarTextStyle: TextStyles.appBar,
  ),
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: MyColors.primary.shade900,
      textStyle: TextStyles.elevatedButton,
    ),
  ),
  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: TextStyles.textButton,
      shadowColor: MyColors.primary.shade500,
    ),
  ),
);
```

My TextStyles:

```
  static final textButton = TextStyle(
    color: MyColors.primary.shade500,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    letterSpacing: 1.25,
  );

  static const elevatedButton = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    letterSpacing: 0.25,
  );
```

Comment: `MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
style: ButtonStyle(
foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 64)),
),
),
), ...)
`

Comment: @pskink Could you elaborate?

Comment: ok so i used `style: TextButton.styleFrom` and it works too if you set `primary` property, for more info check https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons